# gtsummary integer not being treated as continuous variable in output

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to create a summary table using the gtsummary() function. My dataset contains an integer (variable age), for which I am trying to attain the mean and SD in the gtsummary output.

Unfortunately, the integer is NOT being treated as a continuous variable. How do I go about fixing this issue?

I tried to age = mutate(as.numeric(age)), however this didn't work. I can't find any solutions for this problem online.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Below is the relevant code:

```
df <- data.frame (age  = c(5.0, 5.2, 6.0, 7.1, 8.0, 9.0, 10.5, 4.1, 2.3),
                  sex = c("male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "female", "male"))

table1 <- df %>%
  select(age, sex) %>%
  tbl_summary(statistic = list(
    all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
    all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    label = list(age ~ "Age", 
                 sex    ~ "Sex")) %>%
  bold_labels()

table1
```

Comment: Hm. I just tested on the default example. And from my checks if there are less than 10 different values the "numeric"s are treated like categorical variables too,  i.e. you get one row per value. But haven't found an option to change that behavior.

Comment: The function's help file specifically outlines the 10 unique level threshold and includes instructions for changing the default: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_summary.html#type-argument-1